# Powershell Invoke-RestMethod Pagenation data

Tags: powershell, rest

I'm trying to get paginated data from the Marketo API.
However, with the code below, only the default 20 items can be retrieved.
Windows version Powershell 7.4.1

```
$clientId = "************************************"
$clientSecret = "********************************"
$baseURL = "https://XXX-XXX-XXX.mktorest.com"

$tokenEndpoint = "$baseURL/identity/oauth/token"

$tokenRequestBody = @{
    grant_type    = "client_credentials"
    client_id     = $clientId
    client_secret = $clientSecret
}

$tokenResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $tokenEndpoint -Method Post -Body $tokenRequestBody

$accessToken = $tokenResponse.access_token

$endpoint = "$baseURL/rest/asset/v1/forms.json"

$page = 1
$pageSize = 20

do {
    $headers = @{
        Authorization = "Bearer $accessToken"
        ContentType   = "application/json"
    }

    $queryParams = @{
        offset   = ($page - 1) * $pageSize
        maxReturn = $pageSize
    }

    $uri = "$endpoint?$($queryParams | ForEach-Object { "$($_.Key)=$($_.Value)" })"

    $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method Get -Headers $headers

    if ($response.success -eq $true) {
        $formsData = $response.result

        foreach ($form in $formsData) {
            Write-Output "Form ID: $($form.id), Name: $($form.name), Description: $($form.description)"
        }

        $page++
    } else {
        Write-Output "Error: $($response.errors)"
        break
    }
} while ($response.moreResult -eq $true)
```

When executed with VSCode, 20 data and the following are displayed.

```
Invalid URI: The hostname could not be parsed.
```

Can someone help me to modify the script below to return all data?

Answer (score 1):

After modifying it as below, I got the desired result.

```
$uri = "$endpoint?$($queryParams | ForEach-Object { "$($_.Key)=$($_.Value)" })"
↓
$uri = "$endpoint?$($queryParams | ForEach-Object { "$($_.Key)=$($_.Value)" })" -join "&"
```